# Method to refer to MSDN and not have to correct the links every few months?

Tags: url, hyperlink, msdn

How can I link to the documentation of functions, structures and classes on MSDN in a persistent manner?

Microsoft appears to break the links every few months for no good reason and I haven't come across a method to refer to the topics in a way that - for example - points to the latest version of the documentation *always*. Is there such a way?

**Edit:** what I am looking for is a way to "permalink" a certain piece of documentation without having to worry about it disappearing. Preferably those names should be meaningful as well, instead of the usual combination of letters and digits followed by `.asp` or `.aspx`, such as: `http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms923723.aspx`.

NB: I realize that, even though this relates to programming, it may not be suitable for SO, so feel free to suggest moving it to a more appropriate SE site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please give an example. The links don't actually break that often.

For instance, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.aspx will never break, but http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest(v=vs.110).aspx is specific to the version.

Comment: The specific links seem to break quite often, basically whenever MS chooses to remove specific older documentation (between VS 6 and 7, 7 and 8 ...). Beside that how can I get the generic link (first of your examples) without having to edit my address bar and *testing*? Btw: that would answer my question.

Comment: Wow, you might actually have to remove the "(v=vs.110)" from the URL. I agree. That's too much work. Alternatively, you could be sure to be browsing the current version, since those links often don't have the version number in them. And, if your greatest complaint involves the time between Visual Studio 2003 and Visual Studio 2005, then you don't have much of a complaint.

Comment: please don't take offense at my earnest question. Besides, often those pages are *not* having a meaningful name such as your example but some combination of letters and digits followed by `.asp` or `.aspx` ... and those **indeed** break a lot over time, though I imagine your example may be the "new way" and perhaps is the way to go finally?! I just want literally a way to "permalink" to the MSDN documentation and was asking whether there is a way to do so. Still +1 for getting me closer.